# How do you track your professional achievements?

Tags: resume, performance-reviews

I find it extremely important to track my professional achievements because ultimately they explain the value I’ve created for my organization.

What tools are you using to track and manage your achievements and the value you’ve created for your employer? Specifically related to updating your resume and leveraging them for your upcoming performance review.

For those that by chance are unaware as to what an achievement is: Did you introduce a new customer service initiative that drove satisfaction by 10%? Did you grow sales by $20M?

Comment: Hey @joeqwerty I think it’s pretty well defined above. Things you do that create value for your employer. Did you introduce a new customer service initiative that drove satisfaction up by 10%? Did you create an algorithm that is used to replenish $20M? Etc.

Comment: It's pretty well defined above? Where? This is your question: `I find it extremely important to track my professional achievements because ultimately they explain the value I’ve created for my organization. What tools are you using to track and manage your achievements and the value you’ve created for your employer?`. I don't see achievements defined in that, and you make a vague statement about "creating value". Why don't you put those examples in your question? That would help others to understand the kinds of things you're talking about.

Comment: @joeqwerty achievements in the world of resumes and performance reviews are well known, it isn’t new terminology. Great responses have already been provided. I’d love to read your response and what you’re using for your achievements.

Comment: JC, can you give us some commentary on why obvious answers like "write it in a word processing doc" aren't suitable? Is there something specific about the way you need to track things that's driving you to look for a more sophisticated answer? Are you literally interested just in a way to record achievements in order to track them, or are you more interested in calculating, determining, categorizing, or measuring when it comes to the tool you're hoping to find?

Comment: @dwizum it isn't supposed to be a sophisticated question, if you use Word or G Docs, great! If you're using something else, a tool, a piece of software, or anything else, even better let's hear it. If your answer is constructive like those below, man that's awesome, and exactly the type of constructive dialogue I was looking for. You bring up great points, I think part of tracking your achievements can be how you are "calculating, determining, categorizing, or measuring" them. I'd love to hear how you're doing.

Comment: @Kevin I appreciate the sarcasm, unfortunately, I thought the level of conversation was going to be elevated like some of the folks have contributed in their answers. I'd love to hear how you're tweeting about securing $20M in new business for your organization and how you're using that to discuss it with your manager.

Comment: Are you asking this because you're personally interested in a way to track your achievements? Or is it related to the project you have linked in your profile?

Comment: @dwizum Thanks for asking. I’m interested in learning what professionals are using to track their achievements and how they’re doing it. It’s something I’ve asked in other communities as well.

Comment: @dwizum I’d love to read how you’re doing. Otherwise I think those that have answered have been very constructive and helpful and I think I’ve got what I’m looking for.

Comment: @dwizum Thanks for pointing this out. Now I'm wondering whether this question will turn into a spammy sort of thing for the product the OP represents or perhaps the question is merely market research.

Comment: @shoover interestingly I haven’t mentioned anything about my day job or project. Quite frankly I could’ve been a Career Coach asking the question. It’s pretty irrelevant at this point. If you want shut down the question. Quite frankly this has been quite a ridiculous experience for a very simple straightforward question that anyone in a professional setting deals with. Not sure what the expectations are here, but maybe there needs to be a toning down of question policing.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of this experience has been ridiculous for you or what "policing" you're concerned about. I asked the question out of curiosity. If anything, clarifying the context of your question may help people respond more appropriately. I did also ask on meta if there are guidelines for this sort of question, but again that was merely a question to get clarification.

Comment: @dwizum oh that’s not even my concern, again I don’t care whether it’s my day job or project or whatever it is. It shouldn’t even matter, I’m stating the fact that while users are actually responding the question with substantial information, this turned into a nitpicking over the question. This is the exact issue with StackOverflow in general.

Comment: What you are calling an issue is the way the site is designed to work, because it's the best way for a Q & A format to refine content. No one is policing or nitpicking. People are using comments to help clarify the question in order to provide more relevant answers. If that's offensive, or seems ridiculous to you, I guess you could choose to ignore or flag the comments.

Comment: At this point it feels like we are off on a tangent, and it would probably be better to continue in meta or in chat.

Comment: [Meta question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/do-we-have-guidelines-for-commercial-research-oriented-questions?cb=1) taking this one as an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to provide another answer since the existing one is more focused around keeping your CV updated, but your tag and title suggest a performance review within your company.

What I personally do is to keep a personal log of events in which I track the things that went well, the things that didn't go as planned or could have been improved, and any other piece of information that could be used in the performance review (e.g. receiving feedback from another person). I update this log periodically, every time a relevant event takes place. If I have metrics to back my event, even better.

If you have set objectives with your manager or if your company has certain values or goals you should try to adhere or aim for, make sure you note how your item in your log relates to that.

Personally, following this approach makes the preparation of my performance review easier since I don't have to start remembering everything that happened in the last X months. All I have to do is copy-paste my log and amend it for the review.

I think it's important, as I've already mentioned, to keep track of the things that could have gone better. On the one hand, it's great for you to have them in your log so you don't forget about them and you don't make the same mistake twice. On the other hand, it's key to show that you're aware of your areas that need improvement and that no matter how your performance review goes, you can do better.

Regarding the tools to do this, there are a few options, but it's all down to a matter of preference. If your company has a good software in place for reviews, maybe you can use that. Otherwise, any notes or text software that is available in the Cloud and accessible from multiple devices would be perfect. I do think it's good to be able to access it from anywhere so you don't miss the chance to track an important event.

Last but not least and to relate to the other answer, the best achievements of your log can be used to keep your CV up-to-date.

I hope this helps, but feel free to ask for clarifications or further advice.

Comment: I think it ultimately becomes a chicken-and-egg scenario between "internal" performance tracking and resume updates. If you keep your resume updated, you can always reference that when you have to list achievements on an internal review. If you keep your internal reviews updated, you can always reference that when freshening your resume.

Comment: In a way, yes, you're right @dwizum. However, in my experience, CVs will normally have much more high-level and major achievements when compared to a performance review. Keep in mind a CV will list all the achievements during your work at one company. Performance reviews are usually done every semester and/or every year.

Comment: That's true - but I suppose it depends on your CV writing approach. Generally, what I do is maintain a "master" CV with *way* more detail than I'd ever actually submit to anyone. It's probably 6+ pages right now. Then, when I apply to a job, I trim out the unimportant parts and leave in the parts that best match that job.

Answer (score 7):

Maintain an up-to-date CV. Every time you have something to add, update the CV.

- new job
- new project
- new customer
- new tool
- KPI's
- quality factors
- awards
- effects you produced (made cheaper, made faster, made better quality...)
- and so on...

Answer (score 4):

Mainly **Google Docs** + **Excel**

Here is my method

1) Any time I attend a networking event I add the date + a list of speakers and a few sentences about what I though to a Google Doc spreadsheet called "Networking - Attending".  I also note down if I though the event was good

2) Any time I give a talk or show up someplace because of my company, I add an entry in "Networking - Presenting" spreadsheet with specifics of what I did, who organized it, and who approved it.

3) Anytime I "wrap" a project, whether it is a release of my current project, change of role, internal transfer, etc, I write the entry into my resume that is stored on Google Docs.  This way all the achievements are fresh in my mind.  Any usage info, such as "reached million user mark" get added when I hear about it.  It's better to put too much on your resume, then cut it when you actually job search.

4) Anyone who I've mentored or managed goes in an Excel spreadsheet kept on company hardware along with from/to dates, projects and notes about this person.  Make sure you have enough to give references later on if the person has earned it.

5) Keep a Google Doc Spreadsheet with frequent contacts that you see repeatedly at networking events.  List the last time you saw them and where.  While this doesn't sound like "accomplishments" people like it when you remember their name and the last time you saw them, so it can be really helpful.

You can use all these spreadsheets to list yearly accomplishments very easily.  A quick look at the resume shows "Up'd customer satisfaction 23% 3 years in a row".

Looking at the networking spreadsheet, it's easy to list out all the organizations you've participated in.  With the frequent contacts list, it's easy to see who is an expert at what if your company is hiring.

Answer (score 3):

> What tools are you using to track and manage your achievements and the
>   value you’ve created for your employer?

I originally used a piece of paper, then I switched to a Word doc.

I can't imagine a need for anything more complex than that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Joe, I’ve seen responses go either way depending on the field and profession. Also glad this was all straightened out in Meta, I assume that’s what brought you here.